# How to show popupWindow as drop down onClick of a Recyclerview row element?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popupwindow

I have tried using a code that is working fine except when I click on the last or end rows of the `recyclerview`, the `popupWindow` opens `offscreen`. Is there any way to show the `popupWindow` `upSide` of the view for end rows of the `recyclerview`.
Here is the code I am using:

```
public void showPopup(View v, int _pos) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_row_appointment_option, null);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //TODO do sth here on dismiss
        }
    });

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, v.getScrollX(), v.getScrollY());

    tv_view_profile = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view_profile);
    tv_view_profile.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem I am facing. That popupWindow showing off Screen of the device.]

Comment: share your adapter class where you are calling **showPopup** method

Comment: Add the full code of the adapter , From where you are calling this method.

Comment: I am calling it from adapter class. I am triggering Click listener of that particular view of that row from my activity class using interface. I can share the code for popupWindow instead and its posted below, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for PopupMenu which accepts **AnchorView** -> with the use of that we can get the exact position where we want to show popup -> you can pass AnchroView as View (The three dot imageview)

Here is the great example of it :

https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

And also please use Appcompat version to get **Material** touch in menu.

Ok with custom layout you can go with your regular flow with minor changes --

```
popup.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,
                anchorView.getBottom() - 60);
```

this is just an example for bottom gravity. You can set gravity and margin according to your code.

anchorView =  the view where you want to show this popup. Try this and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need to use a custom layout in the popup. So if I use popupMenu I cannot use my own layout, have to use menu.xml then which I dont want. I need to inflate a custom layout in my popup for which Im doing it using popupWindow. Can u help me to do it using popupWindow? Or Is there any other way you know to show a customized popup? Because menu.xml will not work for me in my case I guess.

Comment: Please recheck the edited answer and let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Sorry, its not working as well. I have tried this before also. Not really working the way I want it to be. Using

Comment: popup.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,
                anchorView.getBottom() - 60);